# How to I create a .prj file with the following projection parameters?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-desktop

I have received shape files that are missing .prj files. The documentation for the shape files describes the projection system as Lambert Conformal Conic and provides the following "Projection parameters".

Projection parameters :

```
Input
Projection geographic
units dd
parameters
output
projection Lambert
spheroid everest
units meters
parameters
23 09 00
28 48 00
90 00 00
26 00 00
2743185.699
914395.233
end
```

Can anyone tell me how I can translate these parameters into a usable .prj file?

As is probably clear from my question, I have a very weak (or no) grasp of of projections and spatial references.

Comment: Are 2743185.699 & 914395.233 parts of the parameters? And Which Part of Asia does your data fall in?

Answer (score 2):

A [Lambert conformal Conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection) projection in [ArcGIS desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003r00000034000000), requires the following parameters:

```
False Easting
False Northing
Central Meridian
Standard Parallel 1
Standard Parallel 2
Scale factor
Latitude of origin
```

Now once we know which parameter is which, we can create a projection file as required.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. In ArcCatalog, right click on your shapefile and go to XY Coordinate system.
2. We cannot directly create a new projection, but we can modify an existing projection.
3. Hence click on `select`.
4. Navigate to `Projected Coordinate System`>>`Continental`>.`Asia`>>`Asia Lambert Conformal Conic`.
5. Press 'Add'
6. Click on 'Modify'
7. You can then edit the parameters one by one by looking at the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is the projection parameters Local Government and Engineering Department of Bangladesh(LGED) uses.
ArcGIS equivalent of this parameter is as below-

```
PROJCS["LCC",GEOGCS["New_Geographic_Coordinate_System",DATUM["D_Everest_Bangladesh",SPHEROID["Everest_Adjustment_1937",6377276.345,300.8017]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",2743185.699],PARAMETER["False_Northing",914395.233],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",90.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",23.15],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",28.8],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",26.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

All the prj files contain above parameters :)